# Dojo When Contentpane have the content attribute as string How to get the id of content attribute?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am studying to be programmed through the dojo. i want to id of GridContainer.
please tell me advice!
my code.

```
 function resTab(formCount,cont){
        var tab=new dijit.layout.ContentPane({
        title:formCount,
        id:''+formCount,
        content:cont,
        class:'tab',
        closable: true
    });
    dijit.byId('tabContainer').addChild(tab); 
}
cont='<div dojoType="dojox.layout.GridContainer" class="test" doLayout="true"     id="gc'+gridCounter+'" region="center" hasResizableColumns="true" opacity="0.3"  nbZones="1" allowAutoScroll="false" withHandles="true" dragHandleClass="dijitTitlePaneTitle" minChildWidth="200" minColWidth="10"></div>';
```

cont have a string that is GridContiner tag.If i want find out the ID value of the string  What should I do?

```
 var selectedTab=registry.byId('tabContainer').get('selectedChildWidget');
```

I would like to solve the above code to the application. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're trying to `GridContainer` without having any knowledge of the real ID (containing `gridCounter`).

You can do that by getting a reference of the `ContentPane` and then using the function [`getChildren()`](https://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.9/dijit/layout/ContentPane#1_9dijit_layout_ContentPane_getChildren).

For example:

```
var tabs = registry.byId("tabContainer"); // Get a reference to the TabContainer
var cPane = tabs.get("selectedChildWidget"); // Get a reference to the ContentPane
var grid = cPane.getChildren()[0]; // Get a reference to the GridContainer
```

Of course, this is when assuming that your `GridContainer` is positioned as the first child of the `ContentPane`.

If you really just want the ID, you can then use:

```
var id = grid.id;
```

An example: http://jsfiddle.net/JaU9v/